# JS - Como fazer loop com base nos dados de um array?

Tags: javascript, array

Boas, eu tenho o seguinte array JS no meu código:

```
var Boletins = 
{
    id:1, items:
    [
        {
            "#": "1",
            "Data": "19 a 25 de Março de 2021",
            "Região": "região de Trás-Os-Montes e Alto Douro",
            "Niveis": "muito elevados",
            "PoleneArvore": "cipreste, pinheiro",
            "PoleneErva": "urtiga, gramíneas"
        },
    id:2, items:
        [
            {
                "#": "10",
                "Data": "26 de Março a 1 de Abril de 2021",
                "Região": "região de Trás-Os-Montes e Alto Douro",
                "Niveis": "muito elevados",
                "PoleneArvore": "plátano, cipreste, pinheiro, carvalhos"
            }]}
```

Gostaria de poder criar um Div em HTML para cada um dos id únicos, neste caso vai até ao id:14 mas estou a ter dúvidas e erros na criação do loop.

```
for (let num in Boletins.id){
    htmlText += '<div class="divBoletim">';    
    htmlText += '<p> Boletim </p>';           
    htmlText += '<h5>ver mais...</h5>';      
    htmlText += '</div>';
}      
$('body').append(htmlText);
```

Contudo, o meu código dá erro no loop e não me cria os divs para cada um dos id presentes no array. Agradeço a ajuda que me possam disponibilizar.

Answer (score -1):

Essa estrutura que você mandou deveria ser um array de objetos e não é, se fosse um array de objetos seria algo mais ou menos assim que você deveria fazer:

**Sua estrutura:**

```
const Boletins = [
{
    id: 1,
    items: [{
            "#": "1",
            "Data": "19 a 25 de Março de 2021",
            "Região": "região de Trás-Os-Montes e Alto Douro",
            "Niveis": "muito elevados",
            "PoleneArvore": "cipreste, pinheiro",
            "PoleneErva": "urtiga, gramíneas"
 }]}, {
    id:2,
    items: [{
                "#": "10",
                "Data": "26 de Março a 1 de Abril de 2021",
                "Região": "região de Trás-Os-Montes e Alto Douro",
                "Niveis": "muito elevados",
                "PoleneArvore": "plátano, cipreste, pinheiro, carvalhos"
}]}];
```

Aí você pode fazer um map: `Boletins.map(bol => bol.items)` ou qualquer tipo laço que percorra esse array (for of, for, forEach, etc...).